# How to Reconnect to all IBM Queue Managers in a cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

We use IBM MQ for some integration between various micro services. The applications are quite critical and we aim for zero down times. We have a cluster of three Queue Managers each one running on a different server (on a separate AWS availability zones) say `QM1 on sever1, QM2 on server2 and QM3 on server3`.

We configure three `ConnectionFactory` like below (note the connection name list differences):

```
var connectionFactory1 = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory1.setConnectionNameList("server1,server2,server3");
conectionFactory1.setPort(1414);
....
var connectionFactory2 = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory2.setConnectionNameList("server2,server3,server1");
conectionFactory2.setPort(1414);
....
var connectionFactory3 = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory3.setConnectionNameList("server3,server1,server2");
conectionFactory3.setPort(1414);
....
```

The idea behind this setup is to be able to utilize all the three Queue Managers at the same time. The first connection factory will consume from `QM1`, the second connection factory will consume from `QM2`, and so on.

From time to time the servers running IBM Queue Managers need to be patched and restarted. When this happens, obviously the queue managers needs to be shut down.
While a Queue Manager is down all the traffic is redirected through the other two Queue Managers in the cluster so the flow of the messages never stops.

While `server1` is down:

- `connectionFactory1` switches to `server2,server3` so consuming from `QM2`
- `connectionFactory2` switches to `server2,server3` so consuming from `QM2`
- `connectionFactory3` switches to `server3,server2` so consuming from `QM3`

After patching server1 we start QM1.

The issue we have is that the three connection factories stay switched as above without reconnecting to `QM1` at all. The only one way we were able to restore the desired state was by restarting the application which is not really a good/acceptable solution.

In our client code we implemented some resiliency patterns to find out when the QM1 comes back up and reset `connectionFactory1` (spring `CachingConnectionFactory` wrapped around `MQQueueConnectionFactory`) as well as stopping  and started all listener containers consuming for that QM1 as prefered queue manager but this had no effect. The only way we could do it was to actually restart Spring Application Context but this is similar to actually restarting the application. And when you have many such applications this is really not a good solution.

I noticed that [MQQueueConnectionFactory](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=jms-mqconnectionfactory) has a method `setClientReconnectOptions(int options) throws javax.jms.JMSException` but reading the comment of that method did not make it very clear to me if that can be used for what we want.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Reconnect options are for re-making the connection after a failure. It will not affect re-making the connection just because the set of connections is unbalanced. This is not an easy problem to solve from inside the application because it does not know about the whole environment. That is why IBM MQ now has a feature called Uniform Clusters with Application Rebalancing which does EXACTLY this. When you start up the recycled queue manager, the cluster (which has a picture of the whole set of client connected applications) notices the imbalance and tells some of the applications to go elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a very good suggestion. As soon as I read your comment, I went to IBM MQ documentation and yes, this is exactly what we want. I know we use IBM MQ 9.x but not sure if is 9.2. If not maybe a good reason for an upgrade. Please publish your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done :-) Added a couple links as well.

Comment: I started changing our code and the infrastructure guys will give me a uniform cluster for testing next week. I guess keeping three connection factories and rotating the connection names list will make no sense now. I would appreciate if you comment on this thought. Thanks.

Comment: Uniform clusters are setup by creating a CCDT group containing all 3 QMs, and also an individual record for each of the 3 QMs as well. Your application can connect to the group name and let MQ decide on the target, or connect to a specific qmgr. I think (but you should test this to be sure) that it's simply the MQCNO_RECONNECT option that causes the rebalancing - even if you directly connected to a specific queue manager initially. So if you need to have a connection to all three QMs for whatever reason, I guess you could continue to do that. You wouldn't need a connection List, just a CCDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconnect options are for re-making the connection after a failure. It will not affect re-making the connection just because the set of connections is unbalanced.

For more about reconnectable clients, see [Reconnectable clients](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=manager-reconnectable-clients) in the IBM Docs.

This is not an easy problem to solve from inside the application because it does not know about the whole environment. That is why IBM MQ now has a feature called Uniform Clusters with Application Rebalancing which does EXACTLY this. When you start up the recycled queue manager, the cluster (which has a picture of the whole set of client connected applications) notices the imbalance and tells some of the applications to go elsewhere. It utilises the client application ability to reconnect as per the above options, but the driver to move to another queue manager comes from the queue manager it is currently connected to, rather than being determined by the client.

The Uniform Clusters feature and Application Balancing were added in IBM MQ V9.1.2 and enhanced in several of the subsequent CD releases. The first LTS release to provide it would therefore be IBM MQ V9.2.0.

For more about Uniform Clusters, see [About uniform clusters](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=cluster-about-uniform-clusters) in the IBM Docs.