# How to connect to an IBM MQ uniform cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I recently posted this [How to reconnect to all IBM MQ queue managers in a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599900/how-to-reconnect-to-all-ibm-queue-managers-in-a-cluster) question and I was suggested that a uniform cluster would be the solution. Reading through the docs it seemed to be exactly what we need.

Our infrastructure guys configured the uniform cluster and I am trying to connect to it and test the functionality.

To connect to that I created a json CCDT file similar with below:

```
{
  "channel":
  [
    {
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server1",
            "port": 1414
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM1"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server2",
            "port": 1414
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM2"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server3",
            "port": 1414
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM3"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server1",
            "port": 1414
          },
          {
          "host": "server2",
          "port": 1414
          },
          {
          "host": "server3",
          "port": 1414
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "*"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

In other words I was trying to create a client connection to each queue manager and a forth one to the group of three queue managers. Initially this entry was not in the file  "queueManager": "*" but when trying to run I was getting **missing required attribute**. That made me put that " * ". The error went away however I am still unable to connect which make me think that my CCDT config is wrong. On the client side I have this `ConnectionFactory` creation:

```
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        if (Objects.isNull(ccdtUrl)) {
            connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList(connectionNameList);
            connectionFactory.setChannel(queueManagerChannel);
            connectionFactory.setPort(connectionPort);
        } else {
            connectionFactory.setCCDTURL(ccdtUrl);
        }
        connectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
        connectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
        connectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(reconnectTimeout);
        connectionFactory.setAppName(applicationName);

        if (sslEnabled) {
            connectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
            connectionFactory.setSSLFipsRequired(sslFipsRequired);
            System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", useIBMCipherMappings);
        }
```

Can you advise about what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it. I haven't used CCDT before.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

Following the provided answer and the comments I ended up with this CCDT definition:

```
{
  "channel":
  [
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server1",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM1"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server2",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM2"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server3",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QM3"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server1",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QMGROUP"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server2",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QMGROUP"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    },
    {
      "connectionManagement":
      {
        "clientWeight": 10,
        "affinity": "none"
      },
      "general":
      {
        "description": "My channel",
        "maximumMessageLength": 4194304
      },
      "name": "CHANNEL.NAME",
      "clientConnection":
      {
        "connection":
        [
          {
            "host": "server3",
            "port": 1415
          }
        ],
        "queueManager": "QMGROUP"
      },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      },
      "type": "clientConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this connection factory implementation on the client side:

```
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        if (Objects.isNull(ccdtUrl)) {
            connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList(connectionNameList);
            connectionFactory.setChannel(queueManagerChannel);
            connectionFactory.setPort(connectionPort);
            if (sslEnabled) {
                connectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
                connectionFactory.setSSLFipsRequired(sslFipsRequired);
                System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", useIBMCipherMappings);
            }
        } else {
            connectionFactory.setCCDTURL(ccdtUrl);
            connectionFactory.setQueueManager("*QMGROUP");
        }
        connectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
        connectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
        connectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(reconnectTimeout);
        connectionFactory.setAppName(applicationName);
```

When deployed we were able to process a message, then we started seeing lots of connection broken exceptions, the service became unhealthy and being restarted.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
```

At this point I am not sure if this was caused by my CCDT configuration and or the way I created connection factory or by the way the cluster was configured. We know that the cluster works OK when the connection factory is not driven by CCDT.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `"queueManager": "*"` use `"queueManager": "QMGROUP"` then specify `connectionFactory.setQueueManager("*QMGROUP");` for it to use that entry.   What version of MQ jars are you using? What version of MQ are the queue managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a CCDT with n x 2 entries.

- 1 entry for each individual queue manager with the queue manager name set to the REAL queue manager name (as you have)
- 1 entry for each individual queue manager with the queue manager name set to the group name - anything you want, I tend to use the Uniform Cluster name.

So just duplicate the first three entries, and then edit the queue manager names.

Also, in your client program, do not set any channel attributes, e.g. channel name, connection name, port number, ssl cipher, as those attributes all come from the CCDT. That looks like what you are doing, but I thought I'd mention it explicitly as I'm not sure where your `sslEnabled` boolean is coming from.

Ensure your reconnect options are not limited to the queue manager, but allow the connection to be sent to another queue manager, so use `WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT` rather than `WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR`.

And as @JoshMc said in his comment, ensure your connect is made using a queue manager name of the group name, whatever it was you chose.

For further reading, this blog post released by Hursley, at the time JMS was supported by Application Rebalancing, might be of interest.

- [Rebalancing JMS applications within a MQ Uniform Cluster in MQ 9.1.3](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/viewdocument/rebalancing-jms-applications-within)

Comment: I would also recommend the following so the client will randomly choose  one of the three entries: `     "connectionManagement": { "clientWeight": 10, "affinity": "none" }`

Comment: Thank you both. I made the changes last night and hope I'll successfully test them today. I'll add this `connectionManagement` setting too. I remember it being mentioned in the docs too. I wished the documentation itself provided not just very basic examples but also more complex setups like mine. If it works I will post my ccdc so others can use it as a reference.

Comment: Applying your suggestions as well as Josh's made our application connect to IBM MQ so your answer is valid. However the application quickly became unstable. I posted my CCDT and connection factory config, please let me know if you spot something that could cause the issue.

Comment: Hi @Julian - can you tell us what version of IBM MQ, both client and queue manager, you are using. JMS support for application rebalancing was introduced in V9.1.3, so if you were using an earlier client version than that, I could imagine that might cause issues. However, if you are using a later version than that, then this is how it is SUPPOSED to work, so if it doesn't, I would suggest raising a case with IBM. There is only so far that external people like us can help as I'm sure you can imagine.

Comment: You guys already helped me lots and I am very grateful for this. We have 9.3.0.1 on the server side and I was using com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0 on the client side. It came as a dependency from com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.5.7 which was the latest available at the time I implemented my JMS library. Checking on maven repository I can see that library was updated and there is now a boot-starter 2.7.9 that brings allclient-9.3.2.0 or a  boot-starter 2.7.8 that brings allclient-9.3.1.0. From the look of it it does not seem to be an allclient-9.3.0.1 to match exactly the server version.

Comment: I guess it should be all good to use either 9.3.2.0 or 9.3.1.0. There are even older versions of boot-starter, the latest one being 3.0.3 but those ones require java 17 whereas we are still on 11.

Comment: There is no need for the server and client to match versions. However, you do need to have the minimum version where support was added into the JMS client. You do seem to have that as 9.2.4 is newer than 9.1.3. So I think you'll have to ask IBM at the point.

Comment: We involved IBM MQ support and our CCDT configuration and connection factory creation code were correct. The only change they advised us to make was to increase the minimum number of consumers to 30 so we have a reasonable big number of consumers. Our setting was set to max of 10 which from the way spring listener containers work, unless there is big load will stay to only one connection. Setting it to 30-60 resolved the issue. However when restarting the queue manager the heath check failed and application was restarted so we could not see the effect of app reconnecting we want.